# You don't have permission to access /nagios/ on this server

Tags: permissions, apache2

I've done a default install of `nagioscore-nagios-4.4.1` including the web server.

I ***CAN*** attach to the webserver via `elinks http://127.0.0.1/nagios/`

But I ***CAN NOT*** attach via the servers external IP `elinks http://176.xxx.xxx.135/nagios/` (or by Chrome on an external machine)

I get the error

```
You don't have permission to access /nagios/ on this server.
```

I've looked through the apache and nagios setup. But I'm not finding what needs to be changed in the apache configuration.

The `/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/nagios.conf` has the require 127.0.0.1 commented out by default.

```
#        Require host 127.0.0.1
```

The `/usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users` appears correct and allows me to login and navigate from `127.0.0.1`

`iptables` is disabled.

**EDIT**

Apache appears to be listening on `:80`, since the apache2 default (test) webpage is working. Just not the `/nagios/`. I'm using the default `vhosts.d/nagios.conf` without any changes (just linked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`). In previous installs of nagios, this file worked out of the box.

```
# SAMPLE CONFIG SNIPPETS FOR APACHE WEB SERVER
#
# This file contains examples of entries that need
# to be incorporated into your Apache web server
# configuration file.  Customize the paths, etc. as
# needed to fit your system.

ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">
#  SSLRequireSSL
   Options ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   <IfVersion >= 2.3>
      <RequireAll>
         Require all granted
#        Require host 127.0.0.1

         AuthName "Nagios Access"
         AuthType Basic
         AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
         Require valid-user
      </RequireAll>
   </IfVersion>
   <IfVersion < 2.3>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
#     Order deny,allow
#     Deny from all
#     Allow from 127.0.0.1

      AuthName "Nagios Access"
      AuthType Basic
      AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
      Require valid-user
   </IfVersion>
</Directory>

Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
#  SSLRequireSSL
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   <IfVersion >= 2.3>
      <RequireAll>
         Require all granted
#        Require host 127.0.0.1

         AuthName "Nagios Access"
         AuthType Basic
         AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
         Require valid-user
      </RequireAll>
   </IfVersion>
   <IfVersion < 2.3>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
#     Order deny,allow
#     Deny from all
#     Allow from 127.0.0.1

      AuthName "Nagios Access"
      AuthType Basic
      AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
      Require valid-user
   </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Have you checked the file system permissions also?

Comment: Check the Apache error logs.

Comment: @Tom, I have checked the permissions - and they look correct. `nagios:nagios rwxrwxr-x` for the files. `www-data` is in the `nagios` group, and `nagios` is in the `www-data` group. I even tired just changing permissions to `777` for everything nagios as a test - but no change.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Even with `Loglevel` set to debug, there's nothing coming out in either the `error.log` or `access.log`. And I don't mean no pertinent errors. I mean nothing appear in either when I attempt to access by the external IP address.

Comment: Is `/nagios/` the only path that results in the 403?

Comment: @Gerald Schneider Yes. The apache2 default page `/` works fine. I dont have anything other than nagios installed.

Comment: So, I let it sit for a few hours - and now it works. I didn't change anything on the server. The only thing I can think of that changed is - I changed my DNS proxy on the client machine (my laptop). Could that have been the issue? I changed the DNS on my laptop BACK as a test - but it DIDNT recreate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the virtualhost of nagios is setup to listen on that address. The error "You don't have permission to access /nagios/ on this server" makes it appear that Apache is listening but doesn't know where /nagios/ is.

Comment: That would rather result in a 404.

Comment: It appears to be listening on `:80`, since the apache2 default (test) webpage is working. Just not the `/nagios/`. I'm using the default `vhosts.d/nagios.conf` without any changes (just linked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Comment: Is your apache version >=2.3 or < 2.3 ? I had this error before and I'm trying to remember exactly what I did to fix it.

Comment: Apache 2.4.10 .......